# Algebraic Simplification only multiplication in one step

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I want to simplify an algebraic expression in Mathematica.

```
In[1] 1/a(2ba+ca+ba)
Out[1] 3b+c
```

but i want to multiply `1/a` only. Not doing addition in same step. like

```
Out [2] (2b+c+b)
```

how can i calculate Out[2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done in a straightforward way. *Mathematica* will automatically evaluate your wanted result `2b+c+b` to `3b+c`. So we have to prevent the addition to be executed. That can be done by inactivating `Plus`:

```
Inactivate[1/a(2 b a + c a + b a), Plus] 


(* (2 a b + a c + a b) / a *)
```

The multiplication is not distributed over `Inactive[Plus]`. So we have to do that ourselves:

```
%  /. x_ Inactive[Plus][y__] :> Inactive[Plus]  @@ (x {y})

(* 2 b + c + b *)
```

This looks like the result you want to have, but observe that the plus sign is grayed. It is `Inactive[Plus]` instead of `Plus`. Activating it again gives the normal *Mathematica* result:

```
Activate[%]

(* 3 b + c *)
```